# Creating a Button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently learning JavaScript. I've been attempting to create a navbar button that opens the menu when clicked. After multiple attempts and changes to the code, I didn't solve the problem.

```js
document.getElementById("navBtn").onclick = function() {abrirNav()};

function abrirNav() {
    document.getElementByID("abrirMenu").classList.toggle("navAberta");
  }
```

```css
.nav .nav-links{
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #ffcc05;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
        max-width: 280px;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 100px;
        row-gap: 25px;
        transition: all 0.4s linear;
    }
    /* Mostra o menu ao clicar no botão */
    .navAberta{
        display: inherit;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
            <div class="logo">AdoptaPet</div>
            <button id="navBtn"><i class="bi bi-list abrirNav"></i></button>
            <ul id="abrirMenu" class="nav-links">
                <i class="bi bi-x fecharNav"></i>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sobre Nós</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Loja</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Cães para Adoção</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Detalhes do Cão</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Adotar</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Favoritos</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contactos</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

The objective would be to open the `<ul>` when clicking the button at the top right of the image.

[image: Navbar]

I appreciate anyone who tries to help,
Best regards.

Comment: Couple of issues.  First, you should have the `navAberta` be `display:none`, make that a default, and toggle it in and out.  Otherwise, you have multiple conflicting `display` tags.  Second, the first Javascript line should be in a `windows.onload`.  Third, it's `getElementById`, not `...ID`.

Answer (score 1):

Check for error messages in your console. When I run your code I get

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function

That `D` shouldn't be capitalized.

The 2nd issue is that `.nav .nav-links` has higher precedence than `.navAberta` so that `display: inherit` is never applied. You can also see this in dev tools:

[image]

It's crossed out.

You *can* add a 2nd class to make them the same specificity, or remove one of the classes from the other element.

```js
document.getElementById("navBtn").onclick = function() {
  abrirNav()
};

function abrirNav() {
  document.getElementById("abrirMenu").classList.toggle("navAberta");
}
```

```css
.nav .nav-links {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffcc05;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 280px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  row-gap: 25px;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}


/* Mostra o menu ao clicar no botão */

.nav .navAberta {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="logo">AdoptaPet</div>
  <button id="navBtn">Btn</button>
  <ul id="abrirMenu" class="nav-links">
    <i class="bi bi-x fecharNav"></i>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Sobre Nós</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Loja</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Cães para Adoção</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Detalhes do Cão</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Adotar</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Favoritos</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contactos</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I aprecciate your help, i had added that .nav before it still didn't work, turns out it was the capital D that wasn't allowing the code to work. I feel stupid, ty and sry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript is incorrect. You would have to define the `onclick` attribute in html.

Here is the updated code:

```js
function abrirNav() {  document.getElementById("abrirMenu").classList.toggle("navAberta");
}
```

```css
.nav .nav-links {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffcc05;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 280px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  row-gap: 25px;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}


/* Mostra o menu ao clicar no botão */

.nav .navAberta {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="logo">AdoptaPet</div>
  <button id="navBtn" onclick="abrirNav()">Btn</button>
  <ul id="abrirMenu" class="nav-links">
    <i class="bi bi-x fecharNav"></i>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Sobre Nós</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Loja</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Cães para Adoção</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Detalhes do Cão</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Adotar</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Favoritos</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contactos</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```